# Setting dynamic key of new object in JavaScript like { [key] : "value" }

Tags: javascript, object

I just found out that it's possible to create an object and set the key dynamically in the curly braces without needing a second line.

```
var a = "dynamicKey";
var obj = {[a]: "value"}
```

vs

```
var a = "dynamicKey";
var obj = {};
obj[a] = "value";
```

Is this something that was always possible or is in some spec (ES3, ES5)?

Comment: The second code is the correct

Comment: But the first works. Try it in your console

Comment: The first version (with brackets) was *introduced in ES6* and is now accessible in some newer browsers e.g. current version of Chrome. Current best practice is to compile ES6 Javascript to ES5 version via e.g. babel.js or other transcompilers so if you want to deploy this code to web it is better to stick with ES5 and use second syntax or to go with ES6 and use transcompilation

Comment: Yeah, but then what's the exact question?

Comment: The exact question was since when it's supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) and is supported since ES6/JavaScript2015. Also check 'computed property keys' section [here](http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/). You can also check the [ES6/Javascript2015 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) directly (search for 'bracket notation').

ES6/Javascript2015 is currently not supported by all browsers, thus it's best practice to transpile ES6/Javascript2015 to ES5 with tools like [babel](https://github.com/babel) or to use the old way of setting properties, which you also provided.

Webkit (for example Chrome) is now [100% ES6/Javascript2015 compatible](https://twitter.com/webkit/status/728643624464883712). If you just need to support Chrome/Webkit browsers, you don't have to transpile the ES5 anymore.